# Isoline - Service area too small

Tags: here-api

I want to create isolines around point locations (public transport nodes) that indicate the service area that can be reached within max. 1 km of walkable distance (with steps of 200 m). When looking at the output, it seems that many of those service areas are not large enough. There are often pieces of road that should be included in the area (as they are within 1 km distance) but they are not. I included a screenshot of one of the service areas below to illustrate.

I this an issue that can be resolved or not?

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tua2t.png)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have to consider the performance of service when calculating the isoline. For this reason, the Isoline service have constraints on the range value.

Please check the below screenshot related to range object and its maximum value.

[image]

[image]